# How To Make A Profile Screen

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-realtime-database, profile

Im Trying To Make A User Profile After I Sign Up

How do I properly upload an user info to the profile screen from the firebase database :

**top of the code**

```
@IBOutlet weak var UsernameText: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var ProfileImage: UIImageView!

    @IBOutlet weak var DisplayText: UILabel!

    var DatabaseRef: DatabaseReference!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


DatabaseRef = Database.database().reference()
 let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser ? .uid
 DatabaseRef.child("users").child(userID!).observeSingleEvent( of: .value, with: {
    (snapshot) in
    // Get user value
    let value = snapshot.value as ? NSDictionary
    let username = value ? ["username"] as ? String ? ? "username"
    let dict: Dictionary < AnyHashable, Any > ? = ["photo": "url of photo"]

    if let profileImageUrl = dict ? ["photo"] as ? String,
     let url = URL(string: profileImageUrl) {
   URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {
     (data, response, error) in
     DispatchQueue.main.async {
      if let imageData = data {
       self.ProfileImage.image = UIImage(data: imageData)
      } else {

      }
     }
     self.UsernameText.text = username
     self.DisplayText.text = username

     print(error ? .localizedDescription as Any)
     return
```

Comment: its uploading to the firebase but the user profile never updates the user info I have all the outlets attached to the proper code I'm not understanding why no sudden change

Comment: i updated it, I have a sign up screen that when the user plug they userinfo into it it goes directly to firebase I need that same info to pop up on my user profile so it shows they that made an account

Comment: correct as well as the username and display name does not show either

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 if let profileImageUrl = dict["photo"] as? String
```

and make sure profileImageUrl is the actual url of the photo